# How do I align a div to the top right corner of my <img>?

Tags: html, css

I have an image:

```css
img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: "1px solid black";
}
```

```html
<img src='/image.jpg' alt='An image'>
```

Now what I want to do is align a div in such a way such that it's in the top right corner of my `img`. Like this:
[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just put it inside a parent div and make another div inside parent div.

Used absolute positioning on little div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<style>
  .mother {
    margin: 5px;
    background: black;
    border: 2px solid lightgreen;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  .topRight {
    background: white;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 25px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 4px solid crimson;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gold;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="mother">
    <div class="topRight">gg</div>
    <img src='/image.jpg' alt='An image'>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```